# Доступ к ListBox'у, находящемуся в другом ListBox'e

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть разметка:

```
<ListBox x:Name="LogBox" >
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
             <DataTemplate>
                 <Grid Width="330" x:Name="CUGrid">
                    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Logs}">
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                             <DataTemplate>
                                <Grid>
                                    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                            <Label Content="Начало: "></Label>
                                            <Label Content="{Binding StartTime}" ></Label>
                                        </StackPanel>
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                            <Label Content="Конец: " ></Label>
                                            <Label Content="{Binding EndTime}"></Label>
                                        </StackPanel>
                                     </StackPanel>
                                     <Label Content="{Binding Passed}"></Label>
                                 </Grid>
                             </DataTemplate>
                         </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                     </ListBox>
                     <Grid>
                         <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center">
                             <Label Content="{Binding Date}"></Label>
                            <Label Content="{Binding Total}"></Label>
                            <Label Content="{Binding Passed}"></Label>
                         </StackPanel>
                     </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

И класс:

```
class ForLB
    {
        public string Date { get; set; }
        public string Total { get; set; }
        public string Passed { get; set; }
        public List<DayLogLB> Logs { get; set; }
        public ForLB()
        {
            Logs = new List<DayLogLB>();
        }
        public class DayLogLB
        {
            public string StartTime { get; set; }
            public string EndTime { get; set; }
            public string Passed { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

Как мне заполнять дочерний ListBox? Сейчас, при добавлении необходимых элементов в допустим нулевой элемент главного ListBox'a при помощи `(LogBox[0] as ForLB).Logs.Add(...)` способ не работает.

Что можно сделать в этом случае?

Comment: А можно убрать из кода лишнее, оставив только необходимое? Например, `x:Name="LogBox" Margin="0,36,0,0" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"` явно не относится к вопросу.

Comment: P. S.: Если у вас вложенные листбоксы, возможно, вам в реальности нужен `TreeView` и `HierarchicalDataTemplate`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для того, чтобы добавление в список подхватывалось, вам нужен вместо `List<T>` контейнер, реализующий интерфейс `INotifyCollectionChanged`. Обычно используют `ObservableCollection<T>`.

Попробуйте заменить `public List<DayLogLB> Logs { get; set; }` на `public ObservableCollection<DayLogLB> Logs { get; set; }`.

---

Да, поскольку ваш класс `ForLB` не реализует `INotifyPropertyChanged` (обратите внимание, не `INotifyCollectionChanged`), то изменения в значениях свойств наподобие `Date` и `Total` подхватываться не будут. Поэтому имеет смысл либо реализовать `INotifyPropertyChanged`, либо убрать сеттеры и устанавливать значения в конструкторе.